# Separar o resultado que aparece em os.getcwd() para conseguir exibir somente o c:\

Tags: python

> Faça um programa que exibe o diretório atual (o qual você está salvando os seus programas), a unidade de disco utilizada, o nome de usuário do sistema e a pasta atual. Considere o exemplo abaixo. Dica utilize a função `split`.

```
Diretorio Atual = C:\Users\monte\PycharmProjects\Aula3
Unidade do Disco = C:
Nome do Usuario = monte
Pasta Atual = Aula3
```

Tentei usar o `split` e o programa não aceitou

```
import os
os.getcwd()
os.getlogin()
lista = []
print(os.getcwd())
print(os.getlogin())
lista.append(os.getcwd()) #variável colocada na lista
```

Comment: Em que momento você tentou usar o `split`? Por que o programa não aceitou, deu erro?

Comment: tentei usar após o "lista.append(os.getcwd()).
apareceu o erro:

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\cwo\Downloads\lista.py", line 82, in <module>
    lista.split()
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'split'

Comment: A função `split` serve para quebrar uma *string* em pedaços, você a utilizou em uma lista.

Comment: apareceu este resultado para mim: C:\Users\cwo\Downloads
então tentei usar a função para separar o c: do que aparece

Comment: Acho que esta é a resposta, confere para mim por favor.

import os
os.getcwd()
os.getlogin()
lista = []
print('Diretorio Atual: ', os.getcwd())
print('Usuario: ', os.getlogin())
lista.append(os.getcwd())
lista = ''.join(lista)
lista.split()
print('Unidade de Disco: ',lista[0:2])
print('Pasta Atual: ',lista[13:22])

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use as funções do `os.path`!

Supondo que você tem uma variável `d` com o diretório que quer (pode usar `os.getcwd()` para pegar o diretorio atual, mas no exemplo abaixo vou usar o mesmo diretório que você exemplificou, para ilustrar):

```
>>> # d = os.getcwd()
>>> d = r'C:\Users\monte\PycharmProjects\Aula3'
```

Para pegar o drive, use `os.path.splitdrive`

```
>>> drive, resto = os.path.splitdrive(d)
>>> print(drive)
C:
```

Para pegar a pasta atual, use `os.path.basename`:

```
>>> pasta = os.path.basename(d)
>>> print(pasta)
Aula3
```

Veja mais na [documentação do `os.path` aqui](https://docs.python.org/library/os.path).

Comment: Muito obrigado nosklo.
meu programa ficou assim:
import os
os.getcwd()
os.getlogin()
lista = []
print('Diretorio Atual:', os.getcwd())
print('Usuario:', os.getlogin())
lista.append(os.getcwd())
lista = ''.join(lista)
lista.split()
print('Unidade de Disco:',lista[0:2])
#print('Pasta Atual:',lista[13:22])

Comment: Porém usei o basename e não tive o retorno do diretório atual.

Comment: Consegui montar o programa.
Grato pela ajuda!!!

import os
os.getcwd()
os.getlogin()
d = os.getcwd()
lista = []
print('Diretorio Atual:', os.getcwd())
print('Usuario:', os.getlogin())
lista.append(os.getcwd())
pasta_atual = os.path.basename(d)
lista = ''.join(lista)
lista.split()
print('Unidade de Disco:',lista[0:2])
print('Pasta Atual: ',pasta_atual)

Answer (score 0):

Utilizando a função `split` como dito acima, sugiro a seguinte solução:

Considerar o diretório a seguir como exemplo:

```
d = r"C:\Users\monte\PycharmProjects\Aula3"
# OU 
d = "C:\\Users\\monte\\PycharmProjects\\Aula3"
```

Note que no segundo caso foi colocado contra barras duplas `\\`. Isso se faz necessário para que o Python reconheça a contra barra `\` como um caracter.

A função `split` entra a seguir:

```
d_list = d.split("\\")
print(d_list)
```

```
['C:', 'Users', 'monte', 'PycharmProjects', 'Aula3']
```

Note que dessa forma já temos todos os campos desejados separados. Agora basta pegar os campos de interesse:

```
Unidade_do_Disco = d_list[0]
Nome_do_Usuario = d_list[2]
Pasta_Atual = d_list[-1]
```

Uma última observação: quando se chama a função `split` sem nenhum parâmetro, o padrão é separar a string por espaços em branco. Ao passar o parâmetro, a string é separada utilizando o parâmetro passado como critério.

Answer (score 0):

Faça um programa que exibe o diretório atual (o qual você está salvando os seus programas), a unidade de disco utilizada, o nome de usuário do sistema e a pasta atual.
Considere o exemplo abaixo. Dica utilize a função split.

Diretorio Atual = C:\Users\monte\PycharmProjects\Aula3

Unidade do Disco = C:

Nome do Usuario = monte

Pasta Atual = Aula3

```
import os
os.getcwd()
os.getlogin()
d = os.getcwd()
lista = []
print('Diretorio Atual:', os.getcwd())
print('Usuario:', os.getlogin())
lista.append(os.getcwd())
pasta_atual = os.path.basename(d)
lista = ''.join(lista)
lista.split()
print('Unidade de Disco:',lista[0:2])
print('Pasta Atual: ',pasta_atual)
```